# Android run time permission for eclipse IDE

Tags: android, eclipse, android-studio

I am writing an application in Eclipse with `API` support `marshmallow`. What I observed is that the application doesn't require run time permission (danger permission like read contacts, storage ext.) while building build from `eclipse` IDE.

But if I do same from Android Studio, the app gets crash as no permission (didn't placed run time permission code).

Why it is so?

Comment: you need to add your runtime permission manually in your code in case you are using eclipse IDE for development

Comment: @Anjali kindly share that code. Thanks You

Comment: https://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/things-you-need-to-know-about-android-m-permission-developer-edition/en will help you

Comment: @Anjali, yes it help me. But why its giving issue doing same from android studio with gradle. Any idea?